# How to add time to the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on knex.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, knex.js

I have such `knex` statement:

```
return knex(table).insert({
            id: uuid.v4(),
            ...data,
            created_at: knex.raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
            updated_at: knex.raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
            expired_at: ...
        })
```

There are 3 timestamp fields `created_at`, `updated_at` and `expired_at`. There is no problem with 2 first, but I have no idea, how to add `expired_at` like +1 minute.

On pseudocode I would look like:

`expired_at: knex.raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 1 minute')`

So, how can I add time using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `knex.fn.now()` to execute `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` function on the database and you will need to use mysql built in methods to calculate your future date

have a look on mysql [date functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) in the offical doc

for example:

```js
knex.raw('SELECT date_add(?, INTERVAL ? day)', [knex.fn.now(), 1])
```